# Windows command line affected by AMD/Intel differences?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I think that some of my software is affected by the difference from Intel and AMD, but it's hard to tell if it's the hardware or if windows is setting some sort of flag. some of my applications that run on the command line work fine in Intel, but on AMD they report that "/AMD was unexpected at this time".
I checked through the file to see if that was an error string contained within, and lo and behold it wasn't. I tried looking at any files that it might have called, and there wasn't that string in those either. so the batch files aren't throwing an error, I figure it must be something that windows is adding, but at the same time it is messing with the flow. 
what is this flag and how can I stop windows from adding it?
(this is probably an obscure question; I couldn't find any answers on google because searching the keywords only brought up articles about AMD and people with the name of the program rather then forum topics or anything about it)
edit:

REM echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM For a good explanation of delayed variable expansion type set /? at the command prompt
REM it is only explained in the command line help not the windows help

REM   -------------- SETUP THE SCRIPT VARIABLES -------------------------

set WORLD_PARAMETERS=
set SIDE_PARAMETERS=
set MUNGE_LOAD=0
set MUNGE_SIDE=0
set MUNGE_COMMON=0
set MUNGE_SHELL=0
set MUNGE_MOVIES=0
set MUNGE_LOCALIZE=0
set MUNGE_SOUND=0
set MUNGE_PLATFORM=PC
set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=ENGLISH
set MUNGE_LANGDIR=ENG
set MUNGE_ALL=1
set DISPLAY_MESSAGES=1
set XBOX_COPY=0

REM   -------------- PROCESS COMMAND LINE ARGS -------------------------

:whilescriptparameters
if "%1"=="" goto endscriptparameters

REM **NOTE**
REM the first goto statement inside of the compound conditional seems to help variable
REM expansion.  It is needed so it doesn't expand all of the variable inside the
REM conditional before it runs the statements.  Unfortunately we can use the delayed
REM expansion operator "!" on the special variables %0-%9

```
if /i "%1"=="/WORLD" (
    REM this goto statement is needed read note above
    goto :whileworldparameters
    :whileworldparameters
    shift
    set parameter=%1
    if "!parameter!" == "" goto whilescriptparameters
    if "!parameter:~0,1!" == "/" goto whilescriptparameters
        set WORLD_PARAMETERS=!parameter! !WORLD_PARAMETERS!
        set MUNGE_ALL=0
    goto whileworldparameters
) else if /i "%1"=="/SIDE" (
    REM this goto statement is needed read note above
    goto :whilesideparameters
    :whilesideparameters
    shift
    set parameter=%1
    if "!parameter!" == "" goto whilescriptparameters
    if "!parameter:~0,1!" == "/" goto whilescriptparameters
        set SIDE_PARAMETERS=!parameter! !SIDE_PARAMETERS!
        set MUNGE_ALL=0
    goto whilesideparameters
) else if /i "%1"=="/LOAD" (
    set MUNGE_LOAD=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/NOMESSAGES" (
    set DISPLAY_MESSAGES=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/SOUND" (
    set MUNGE_SOUND=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
    set MUNGESTREAMS=1
    REM this goto statement is needed read note above
    goto :whilesoundparameters
    :whilesoundparameters
    shift
    set parameter=%1
    if "!parameter!" == "" (
        goto whilescriptparameters
    ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="NOSTREAMS" (
        set MUNGESTREAMS=0
    ) else if "!parameter:~0,1!" == "/" (
        goto whilescriptparameters
    ) else (
        set SOUNDLVL=!parameter! !SOUNDLVL!
        set MUNGE_ALL=0
    )
    goto whilesoundparameters
) else if /i "%1"=="/COMMON" (
    set MUNGE_COMMON=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/SHELL" (
    set MUNGE_SHELL=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/MOVIES" (
    set MUNGE_MOVIES=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/LOCALIZE" (
    set MUNGE_LOCALIZE=1
    set MUNGE_ALL=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/NOXBOXCOPY" (
    set XBOX_COPY=0
) else if /i "%1"=="/PLATFORM" (

    REM this goto statement is needed read note above
    goto :whileplatformparameters
    :whileplatformparameters
    shift
    set parameter=%1

    if /i "!parameter!"=="PC" (
        set MUNGE_PLATFORM=PC
    ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="PS2" (
        set MUNGE_PLATFORM=PS2
    ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="XBOX" (
        set MUNGE_PLATFORM=XBOX
    ) else (
        echo "
        echo "Error (Invalid Platform Parameter): %1
        echo "
        goto PRINT_USAGE_AND_EXIT
    )

    shift
    goto whilescriptparameters

) else if /i "%1"=="/LANGUAGE" (

    REM this goto statement is needed read note above
    goto :whilelanguageparameters
    :whilelanguageparameters
    shift
    set parameter=%1

    if /i "!parameter!"=="ENGLISH" (
        set MUNGE_PLATFORM=ENGLISH
        set MUNGE_LANGDIR=ENG
    ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="UK" (
```

rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=UK
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=UK_
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=UK_
        ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="FRENCH" (
rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=FRENCH
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=FRENCH
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=FRENCH
        ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="GERMAN" (
rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=GERMAN
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=GERMAN
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=GERMAN
        ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="JAPANESE" (
rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=JAPANESE
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=JAPANESE
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=JAPANESE
        ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="ITALIAN" (
rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=ITALIAN
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=ITALIAN
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=ITALIAN
        ) else if /i "!parameter!"=="SPANISH" (
rem         set MUNGE_PLATFORM=SPANISH
            set MUNGE_LANGDIR=SPANISH
            set MUNGE_LANGVERSION=SPANISH
        ) else (
            echo "
            echo "Error (Invalid Language Parameter): %1
            echo "
            goto PRINT_USAGE_AND_EXIT
        )

```
    shift
    goto whilescriptparameters

) else (
    echo "
    echo "Error (Invalid Parameter): %1
    echo "
    goto PRINT_USAGE_AND_EXIT
)
```

shift
goto whilescriptparameters
:endscriptparameters

REM  -----------  POST PROCESS SOME VARIABLES  ---------------

IF /I "%MUNGE_LANGVERSION%"=="ENGLISH" (
    set MUNGE_OVERRIDE_DIR=
) else (
    set MUNGE_OVERRIDE_DIR=%MUNGE_PLATFORM%_%MUNGE_LANGDIR%
)

if /i "%WORLD_PARAMETERS%"=="" ( 
    set WORLD_PARAMETERS=NOTHING 
) else (
    REM see if NOTHING then override the variable
    for %%A in (%WORLD_PARAMETERS%) do (
        if /i "%%A"=="NOTHING" (
            set WORLD_PARAMETERS=NOTHING
        )
    )
)

if /i "%SIDE_PARAMETERS%"=="" ( 
    set SIDE_PARAMETERS=NOTHING 
) else (
    REM see if NOTHING then override the variable
    for %%A in (%SIDE_PARAMETERS%) do (
        if /i "%%A"=="NOTHING" (
            set SIDE_PARAMETERS=NOTHING
        )
    )
)

if %MUNGE_ALL% EQU 1 (
    set WORLD_PARAMETERS=EVERYTHING
    set SIDE_PARAMETERS=EVERYTHING
    set MUNGE_LOAD=1
    set MUNGE_SIDE=1
    set MUNGE_COMMON=1
    set MUNGE_SHELL=1
    set MUNGE_MOVIES=1
    set MUNGE_LOCALIZE=1
    set MUNGE_SOUND=1
)

REM   --------------  SETUP LOGGING  -----------------------

set MUNGE_LOG="%CD%\%MUNGE_PLATFORM%_MungeLog.txt"
if exist %MUNGE_LOG% ( del %MUNGE_LOG% )

REM echo ********************************************************************* >> %MUNGE_LOG%
REM echo munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM% %MUNGE_LANGVERSION% >> %MUNGE_LOG%
REM echo MUNGE_BIN_DIR=%MUNGE_BIN_DIR% >> %MUNGE_LOG%
REM echo MUNGE_OVERRIDE_DIR=*SOURCE*%MUNGE_LANGVERSION% >> %MUNGE_LOG%
REM echo MUNGE_LANGDIR=*SOURCE*%MUNGE_LANGDIR% >> %MUNGE_LOG%
REM echo ********************************************************************* >> %MUNGE_LOG%

if "%MUNGE_BIN_DIR%"=="" (
    set MUNGE_BIN_DIR=%CD%....\ToolsFL\Bin
    REM echo MUNGE_BIN_DIR=%MUNGE_BIN_DIR%
    set PATH=%CD%....\ToolsFL\Bin;%PATH%
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE COMMON  -----------------------

if %MUNGE_COMMON% EQU 1 (
    echo Common\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Common
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd ..
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE SHELL  -----------------------
if %MUNGE_SHELL% EQU 1 (
    echo Shell\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Shell
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd ..
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE LOAD  -----------------------
if %MUNGE_LOAD% EQU 1 (
    echo Load\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Load
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd ..
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE SIDES  -----------------------
if /i "%SIDE_PARAMETERS%" NEQ "NOTHING" (
    echo Sides\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Sides
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM% %SIDE_PARAMETERS%
    cd ..
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE WORLDS  -----------------------
if /i "%WORLD_PARAMETERS%" NEQ "NOTHING" (
    echo Worlds\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Worlds
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM% %WORLD_PARAMETERS%
    cd ..
)

REM   --------------  MUNGE SOUNDS  -----------------------
if %MUNGE_SOUND% EQU 1 (
    echo Sound\munge %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd Sound
    call munge.bat %MUNGE_PLATFORM%
    cd ..
)

if /I "%MUNGE_PLATFORM%"=="XBOX" (
    if %XBOX_COPY% EQU 1 (
        echo Copying files to XBOX...
        echo on
        xbcp -d -y -t -r -f .._lvl_xbox*.lvl xe:\Battlefront2\Data_lvl_xbox\ 2>>%MUNGE_LOG%
        xbcp -d -y -t -r -f .._lvl_xbox*.mvs xe:\Battlefront2\Data_lvl_xbox\ 2>>%MUNGE_LOG%
        xbcp -d -y -t -r -f ..\sound\global\dsstdfx.bin xe:\Battlefront2\Data\ 2>>%MUNGE_LOG%
        REM echo off
    )
)

REM If the munge log has anything in it, view it
if %DISPLAY_MESSAGES% EQU 1 (
    for /f %%i in (%MUNGE_LOG%) do (if %%~zi GTR 0 ( start Notepad.exe %MUNGE_LOG% ) else ( if exist

%MUNGE_LOG% (del %MUNGE_LOG%) ) )
)

REM pause

goto END

REM   --------------  PRINT SCRIPT USAGE AND EXIT  -----------------------
:PRINT_USAGE_AND_EXIT
echo "Usage: munge [/PLATFORM [PC|PS2|XBOX]]
echo "             [/LANGUAGE [ENGLISH|UK|FRENCH|GERMAN|JAPANESE|ITALIAN|SPANISH]]
echo "             [/WORLD [EVERYTHING|NOTHING|  ...]] 
echo "             [/SIDE [EVERYTHING|NOTHING|  ...]] 
echo "             [/LOAD] [/SOUND] [/COMMON] [/SHELL] [/MOVIES] [/LOCALIZE]
echo "
echo "Options:
echo "  If no parameters are specified then everything is munged.
echo "  /PLATFORM The platform to munge the data for (default PC)
echo "  /LANGUAGE The lanuage used for building (default ENGLISH)
echo "  /WORLD    Selectively munges world data.  If "EVERYTHING" or "NOTHING" is 
echo "            specified all world data is munged or not respectively
echo "  /SIDE     Selectively munges side data.  If "EVERYTHING" or "NOTHING" is 
echo "            specified all side data is munged or not respectively
echo "  /LOAD     If specified munges loading screen data
echo "  /SOUND    If specified munges sound data
echo "  /COMMON   If specified munges common data
echo "  /SHELL    If specified munges shell data
echo "  /MOVIES   If specified munges movie data
echo "  /LOCALIZE If specified munges localization data
echo "  /NOXBOXCOPY If specified skips the data copy to the xbox

REM   --------------  EXIT SCRIPT -----------------------
:END

endlocal

Comment: Can you tell us the commands you are running and the specific processors?

Comment: AMD64(A8-6600k APU)
tried to run Munge.bat from SWBF2 mod tools.(only really known to people who ue the program,AFAIK)
(I don't know if this affects other programs, but it would be nice to know if it does before it affects other things)

Comment: Can you edit the batch file and remove any line saying "@ECHO OFF" or similar and rerun it? This will display the individual commands as they are processed by Windows. Then, post the command that failed and the error message.

Comment: C:\BF2_ModTools\data_CAP\_BUILD>REM echo MUNGE_LANGDIR=_SOURCE_ENG >> "C:\BF2_Mo
dTools\data_CAP\_BUILD\PC_MungeLog.txt"

C:\BF2_ModTools\data_CAP\_BUILD>REM echo ***************************************
****************************** >> "C:\BF2_ModTools\data_CAP\_BUILD\PC_MungeLog.t
xt"
\AMD was unexpected at this time.

is the line that states it. oddly, the line in the batch file has absolutely nothing pointing to that flag.

Comment: You would need to post the entire bat file as an edit to your post.

Comment: I can guarantee you the problem with the software isn't cause by the differences between AMD and Intel.

Comment: ok. sorry for the odd question. I thought that might be the case since it had the word AMD in it, but I couldn't tell for sure. thanks for helping me rule that out

Comment: Can you post it to pastebin or somewhere so the formatting isn't messed up?

Comment: The string `\AMD` is coming from your PATH, not your CPU. Look at your PATH environment variable and I bet you'll find something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin` in it. The batch file doesn't correctly handle parentheses in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I change the installation directories, then the path to match as implied, and now the application set works perfectly. thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `\AMD` is coming from your PATH, not your CPU. Look at your PATH environment variable and I bet you'll find something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin` in it. The batch file doesn't correctly handle parentheses in the PATH environment variable.